# Import Excel Data with datetime format to Pandas DF and convert to seconds

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, timedelta

i'm trying to import excel data to a pandas df with datetime format. The data is an export file generated by a porgram to track worktime. My code works fine but i just realised, that i started from thinking that my import file always contains the following format:

| Task | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1900-01-01 22:21:20 |
| Second | 1900-01-01 12:13:14 |

I didn't realise that the Duration starts showing the Date '1900-01-01' whenever the Duration exceeds 24 Hours. The Duration switches to the Date: '1900-01-02' whenever the 'Duration' exceeds 48 hours and so on...

- When the Duration is 6 Hours the value of the cell shows: '06:00:00'
- When the Duration is 28 Hours the value of the cell shows: '1900-01-01 04:00:00
- When the Duration is 50 Hours the value of the cell shows: '1900-01-02 02:00:00

I now need a piece of code to convert this format to seconds as an integer. I've used 'pd.to_timedelta' for this before i realised my mistake but i've always cleared out the date before calculating the total seconds. I didn't find a way to do it straight from the timedelta documentation.

Comment: Could you post an example of your input data in initial format?

Answer (score 0):

Add a prefix if the `Duration` has no date part then compute the difference between datetime and origin (1899-12-31).

```
df['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Duration'].where(df['Duration'].str.len() != 8, 
                         other='1899-12-31 ' + df['Duration'])
)

df['Seconds'] = (df['Duration'] - pd.to_datetime('1899-12-31')) \
                    .dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```

Output:

| Task | Duration | Seconds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Task_a | 1900-01-01 04:00:00 | 100800 |
| Task_b | 1900-01-02 02:00:00 | 180000 |
| Task_c | 1899-12-31 06:00:00 | 21600 |

Comment: @faulehenne. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use if input values are in format `HH:MM:SS`:

```
df['Seconds'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration']).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
```